# Reading a specific line from a .txt file

Tags: c++, notepad

I have a text file full of names:

```
smartgem
marshbraid
seamore
stagstriker
meadowbreath
hydrabrow
startrack
wheatrage
caskreaver
seaash
```

I want to code a random name generator that will copy a specific line from the.txt file and return it.

Comment: are you sure that no lines contain spaces? That may affect the best way to read the file.

Answer (score 2):

While reading in from a file you must start from the beginning and continue on. My best advice would be to read in all of the names, store them in a set, and randomly access them that way if you don't have stringent concerns over efficiency.

You cannot pick a random string from the end of the file without first reading up that name in the file.

You may also want to look at `fseek()` which will allow you to "jump" to a location within the input stream. You could randomly generate an offset and then provide that as an argument to fseek().

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that unless you do one of two things:

1. Generate an index for that file, containing the address of each line, then you can go straight to that address and read it. This index can be stored in many different ways, the easiest one being on a separate file, this way the original file can still be considered a text file, or;
2. Structure the file so that each line starts at a fixed distance in bytes of each other, so you can just go to the line you want by multiplying (desired index * size). This does not mean the texts on each line need to have the same length, you can pad the end of the line with null-terminators (character `'\0'`). In this case it is not recommended to work this file as a text file anymore, but a binary file instead.

You can write a separate program that will generate this index or generate the structured file for your main program to use.

All this of course, considering you want the program to run and read the line without having to load the entire file in memory first. If your program will constantly read lines from the file, you should probably just load the entire file into a `std::vector<std::string>` and then read the lines at will from there.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filePath = "test.txt";
    vector<std::string> qNames;

    ifstream openFile(filePath.data());
    if (openFile.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        while (getline(openFile, line))
        {
            qNames.push_back(line.c_str());
        }
        openFile.close();
    }

    if (!qNames.empty())
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int num = rand();
            int linePos = num % qNames.size();
            cout << qNames.at(linePos).c_str() << endl;
        }   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: So, I tried the code and it doesn't work. It compiles, but don't write anything

Comment: @Arwing this code is composed two parts, one is read file  and push to queue, another is get random lines. which one has an issue?